# What scenarios causes a hard drive UUID to change?

Tags: hard-drive, uuid

What scenarios causes a hard drive UUID to change? Are there any manufacturer assigned unique ids for hard drives that is less likely to change?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [*Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is integrated in the [filesystem](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#S-UUID). By this we can recognize a filesystem by it's unique number to avoid confusion (e.g. when mounting drives).

Anything that affects the file-system will also change its UUID. Under normal circumstances this will be

- formatting a drive
- (re-)partitioning of a drive

Under rare circumstances we may be faced with an external drive that mounts a temporary filesystem (e.g. live systems booting from an USB drive). In this case the UUID may also change.

We can manually assign a fixed UUID to a drive if we wish:

- [How do I change UUID of a disk to whatever I want?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132079/how-do-i-change-uuid-of-a-disk-to-whatever-i-want)

<sup>This would be another scenario where the UUID of a drive changes.</sup>

In case we need manual control over the disk identifiers we may also use a disk LABEL:

- [Constant UUID on USB install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49290/constant-uuid-on-usb-install)