# Brand new network install of Ubuntu 16 Server does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, server, grub2, system-installation

I have been trying to install some form of Ubuntu/Debian/Arch on this old computer of mine (DELL Dimension XPSB773r) for a while and yesterday I tried Ubuntu Server 16 and the network installation went very smoothly. But when I rebooted, it went into GRUB and I got these messages:
[grub errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbjqv.jpg)

When I use`ls` I get this:
[ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve4I4.jpg)

I used `fdisk` in MS-DOS and got this:
[Partition info FDISK drive 2 (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRexG.jpg)|[Partition info FDISK drive 1 (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA8Nm.jpg)|[FDISK drive info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW5k1.jpg)|[Partition info FDISK drive 2 (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa6u1.jpg)

And here is `fdisk` on Ubuntu:
[fdisk ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xivpF.jpg)

And `blkid`: [blkid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmhsS.jpg)

Some info that may be helpful:

- The computer has:

  - 733mhz Pentium III
  - 384mb RAM
  - 2 hard drives
  - 2 CD drives (1 is a DVD)
  - "Legacy Boot" only BIOS (no UEFI)
- The first harddrive has (master drive) :

  - a broken Windows XP, Windows ME and Windows 2000 install
  - a working Windows 2000 Server install
- The second drive has Ubuntu and the rest is just documents and such (This drive is the slave drive)
- Ubuntu doesn't seem to like mounting DVDs (kept getting mounting errors when using a DVD to install, that is why I used a network install on a CD)
- All of the installations are distinctly separated with different partitions

Comment: Have you tried searching for [grub rescue help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting)? It starts with type `ls` to see where you installed your OS...

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't know if that computer even has enough ram to run any flavor of linux, much less Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It probably has more to do with the broken Windows systems, and/or the file system that got created for Ubuntu Server. Boot to a Ubuntu **Desktop** Live CD-RW and get a screenshot of `gparted` and edit that into your question (or show me `sudo fdisk -l`). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Although right now I do not have access to the computer, I do know that the Live CD is larger than 700mb, so I cannot put it on a standard CD, I would have to use a DVD, and DVDs fail to mount for whatever reason. In addition, the computer does not have enough RAM to use the Live filesystem thing.

Comment: @heynnema I cannot access `gparted` or `fdisk` as they say unknown command in GRUB. I tried using it via execute she'll on the network install CD and it said not found. I am trying to use `fdisk` in MS-DOS as I have that readily available. I will edit the question to contain the details.

Comment: `gparted` won't run on a Ubuntu Server Live CD-RW. `fdisk` isn't a GRUB command, but a `terminal` or CLI command, and it will run on your Server CD-RW. Boot the Server CD-RW, and get to the # prompt, and then type the command.

Comment: @not_applicable I don't see any Ubuntu ext4 partitions.

Comment: @not_applicable Now we're making a little progress. Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid`. Also, make sure that your master/slave settings are correct for both HDD's and both DVD's. One master per cable. One slave per cable.

Comment: @heynnema I ran blkid and edited the question with the results

Comment: @not_applicable For some reason Ubuntu didn't get built correctly, as /etc/fstab is looking for the UUID of a disk that doesn't exist on your system. The easy way to fix it is just to reinstall Ubuntu Server. If you'd like to manually try to fix it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/132079/how-do-i-change-uuid-of-a-disk-to-whatever-i-want and set the UUID of /dev/sdb5 to the UUID that you see in your GRUB error image.

Comment: @heynnema I have tried the manual solution and it did not work. Right now I am reinstalling Ubuntu and it seems to be taking much longer than it did before and is asking for more information. I am pretty sure that is a good thing.

Comment: @heynnema The reinstallation completed, but it still did not boot, giving the same errors as before.

Comment: @not_applicable Use `parted` to install a fresh MBR partition table (this will wipe the disk) on /dev/sdb and reinstall again.