# Select default boot partition after cloning a partition (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

I have two disks each with two partitions, one SSD (`/dev/sdb`) which had the main boot partition and another HDD (`/dev/sda`) for backup.

Then I cloned the SSD's main partition (which had the boot) with `dd`, within a USB live environment, to a partition in the backup HDD:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/dev/sda2
```

Now, after I rebooted, the system is starting/booting from the cloned partition `/dev/sda2`!!!

**How do I set which partition the system should startup/boot?** I want to startup with `/dev/sdb2` and NOT `/dev/sda2`, because SSDs are much faster than HDDs.

#### Further info:

Relevant output of `fdisk -l` for both disks:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZAZ-00L
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 350C6598-6531-43D3-9303-26B80124EDDA

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1953128447 1953126400 931,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  1953128448 3907028991 1953900544 931,7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 881AE800-FEC8-4EEA-B0C5-5CAE0E2B47F2

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem
```

Relevant output of `lsblk`:

```
...
sda      8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 931,3G  0 part /mnt/backupA
└─sda2   8:2    0 931,7G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0   931G  0 part
```

Comment: You have cloned your root partition so the clone is identical in every way including the UUID. Chances are your fstab file uses the UUID to identify which partition is to be root. Now there are two it’s a lottery which gets mounted as root. Check your fstab file to confirm it’s using UUID. If it is then you can change the UUID of the clone as per these answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/132079/how-do-i-change-uuid-of-a-disk-to-whatever-i-want#132087 or you can specify the root partition with /dev/sdx notation in both fstab files (original and clone)

Comment: @PonJar thanks a lot, I think it's that, `/etc/fstab`, you got the point because `fstab` is mounting `/` using UUID. Just 1 question: if I want to use `/dev/sdx` notation on `fstab`, will the association between /dev/sdx and the physical disks/partitions be always preserved? Thanks again, and BTW if you want add your comment as answer for me to accept it.

Comment: No, it is not preserved. That's why UUIDs are used. But UUIDs should by design be unique.

Comment: @marco, what about if I use `PARTUUID` in fstab, since I realized they are different between original and cloned partition?

Comment: Generally you do not use dd with gpt partitions. Gpt requires guid in primary partition table, backup partition table & the partition be in sync. You probably now have a bad gpt table. See what this says as best tool for gpt. `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` also check sdb. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802
But you may have to change GUID & UUIDs.

Comment: @oldfred partition tables are good

Comment: @oldfred check my answer, I share my conclusions :)

Comment: @PonJar check my answer, I share my conclusions, thanks again for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

After a full morning around the issue (Linux is challenging :), and thanks to users that commented, and also to share info to other users, I share my conclusions:

- since there are two exact copies of the same data in two different partitions (`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2`) thus also having the same `UUID`, the system was starting always with `/dev/sda2` as root `/`
- apparently `/etc/fstab` root `/` mounting point is ignored except when `UUID` is set. I tried setting `/dev/sdb2 / ...` in `/etc/fstab` in both partitions (original and cloned) and the system was always starting with `/dev/sda2` instead. Therefore don't use `/dev/sdbx` in `/etc/fstab` for the root mounting point `/` because it does not work.
- after investigation, I realized the `UUID` of the root partition was appearing at least  in 3 different locations:

  A) `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`
  B) `/proc/cmdline`
  C) `/etc/fstab`
- Therefore the safest solution, as also suggested in the comments, was to change the `UUID` of the cloned partition.

#### What I did

1. I started the computer in live environment  with USB stick since the partition whose UUID was to be amended must be unmounted
2. Then I ran `tune2fs /dev/sda2 -U random` to alter the UUID of `/dev/sda2` (cloned partition). Before running `tune2fs` I had to run also `e2fsck /dev/sda2 -f -p` because `tune2fs` demanded so.
3. Confirm it with `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Do you still have duplicate partUUID/GUIDs? `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`

Comment: @oldfred no, `partuuid`s are all unique. I actually tried to use `PARTUUID` on `/etc/fstab` since the beginning because that ID was not cloned, but it was not working